# How to solve an apparent conflict between package array and package float?

Tags: tables, floats, packages, arrays, wlscirep

**Problem description / My situation:**
First, I added in the preamble:

```
\RequirePackage{array}
```

to be able to use `\raggedright\arraybackslash` in

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{l>{\raggedright}p{0.35\linewidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}}
```

Then, still in the preamble, I added:

```
\RequirePackage{float}
```

to be able to add the option `[H]` in

```
\begin{figure}[H]
```

**My question:**
If I use the option `[H]`, figures or tables disappear once I compile the latex document. In order to see/show them after compiling the document, I should replace `[H]` by `[!htbp]`, but obviously the figures and tables are not in the exact spot I want/need.
Is there any conflict between the packages `float` and `array`? How can I use both packages and the option `[H]` at the same time? **In other words, if I use `\begin{table*}[H]` or `\begin{figure*}[H]` instead of `\begin{table*}` or `\begin{figure*}`, both Figures and Tables disappear. Please check with and without `[H]`.**

**Minimal working example:**
Note: I am using the ["Scientific Report" template in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns), and I added

```
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{float}
```

inside the file **wlscirep.cls**, there included. Here following the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title of this document}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section*{Section Title}
\lipsum[2-12]

% ------ FIGURE --------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure*}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{stream.jpg}
\caption{A stream.}
\end{figure*}

% ------ TABLE 1 -------------------------------------------------
\begin{table*}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ c c c c c c c c c c}
    \toprule
    &$A$&$B$&$C$&$D$&$E$&$F$&$\alpha$&$\beta$&$\gamma$\\
    \midrule
    London
    & $0.1$ & $5.6$ & $0.5$ & $3$ & $9$ & $0.01$ & $4$  & $8$ & $22$\\
    Paris & $0.8$ & $6$ & $22.4$ & & & & &  $4$ \\
    Moscow & $0.7$ & $54$ & & & & & & &  $45$ \\
    Berlin & $0.2$ & $1.01$ & $41$ & & & & &  $92$ \\
    Rome & $0.9$ & $24$ & $601$ & & & & & &  $9.5$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some values.}
    \label{Tab:table_1}
\end{table*}

% ------ TABLE 2 -------------------------------------------------
\begin{table*}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l>{\raggedright}p{0.35\linewidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    &Feature 1 &Feature 2\\
    \midrule
    London&-&50 \\
    Paris&80&50 \\
    Rome&8&0 \\
    Ottawa&9&7 \\
    Berlin&7&1 \\
    Mexico City&4&2 \\
    Dakar&5&5 \\
    Ljubljana&9&- \\
    Washington D.C.&0&- \\
    Abu Dhabi&1&- \\
    Viennas&2&- \\
    Brussels&2&- \\
    Luanda&3&- \\
    Moscow&0&- \\
    Lima&-&2 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Features for each city.}
    \label{Tab:table_2}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

**After compiling this code:**
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) In a standard setup there should be no issue with `array` and `float`, so whatever is happening is related to some code you are withholding. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My guess is that the document class doesn't like the `[H]` option. Just don't use it. It simply destroys the document's pagination.

Comment: Thanks @campa! I added the "minimal working example" as suggested..

Comment: thanks @egreg, Yes, I removed, but the figure and table are not going exactly where I want, even if I use the option `[!htbp]` in `\begin{table*}[!htbp]` (or in the figure)..

Comment: @limone That's normal: it's very unlikely that the available space on a page can make tables or figures to fit, so LaTeX has the floating mechanism. Captions have precisely the purpose of explaining the figure or table and of providing a number for cross-reference.

Comment: you can not use h or H with `figure*` that is a two column span at the top of the page.

Comment: @egreg thanks a lot for your reply. Maybe I solved my issue.. Indeed in my full case (longer than the "minimal working example"), the Figure was between my two Tables.. while I wanted the Figure to be first, and both Tables just after.. But then, following your indications and just playing a bit with the options on the position, I got what I needed, i.e. the Figure first and the two Table just afterwards. I got in this way: First:
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
\end{figure*}
Then:
\begin{table*}[p]
\end{table*}
And lastly:
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\end{table*}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle many thanks for your kind explanation! :)

Comment: Again many thanks! After your explanation, I have understood! 
By removing the asterisk, i.e. as `\begin{table}[H]` or `\begin{figure}[H]`, it works perfectly!

Comment: Very grateful @DavidCarlisle!